# TransactionSearch with body field condition Suitetalk

Tags: c#, netsuite

This is my case, I want to pull the Vendor Credit that have ApplyList.apply.doc (this is Vendor Bill ID) in a List of Vendor Bill ID.

I have to create a `TransactionSearch`, but I don't know how to apply a condition for this.

For now, I just know to create a search with Status, Type, but that's not enough.

Here is my code :

```
var transactionsSearch = new TransactionSearch
{
    basic = new TransactionSearchBasic
    {                    
        //we only want credits with an "Open" status
        billingStatus = new SearchBooleanField
        {
            searchValue = isOpen,
            searchValueSpecified = true
        },
        //only search for those with a type of "_vendorCredit"
        type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField
        {
            @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
            operatorSpecified = true,
            searchValue = new[] { "_vendorCredit" }
        },

    }
};
```

Comment: I suspect this can't be done purely in SuiteTalk; maybe if you first create a saved search in the UI and then use `TransactionSearchAdvanced`. But to clarify if I've understood this properly, you've already got a list of previously-obtained `InternalId`s of VendorBill transaction records, and you want to select all `VendorCredit`s that have at least one line in their apply list which references any one of those internalIDs in your list of vendor bills?

Comment: Yes right @Klitos, I already have a list of Internal ID of Vendor Bill, can we do that ? thanks god you're here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer.

I have to use property Applied To Transaction in TransactionSearchBasic, that will be an array of Record Ref.